# Frame.destroy() не удаляет Frame и ttk.Progressbar не появляется

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

У меня есть скрипт который делает резервную копию нужных мне папок.
Я сделал для него GUI с помощью tkinter. Весь скрипт и его ГУИ работал нормально и без нареканий даже с большими файлаими в 2Гига и больше.

Решил добавить ttk.Progressbar чтобы было видно сам процесс работы скрипта (чисто из естетических соображений).

Вот сам прогорессбар и его вид когда после его вызова нет далее никакой функции. В этом случае все работает но скрипт дальше не выполняется:

```
    def progress_bar(self):
    
        try:
            self.frame7.destroy()
            if self.frame7.winfo_exists() == 0:
                self.progress = ttk.Progressbar(self.frame8, orient=HORIZONTAL,
                    length=300, mode='indeterminate')
                self.progress.grid(columnspan=20, padx=40)
                self.progress.start()

        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
```

[image: Progressbar_screen]

Но если после старта самого прогрессбара, добавить функцию выполнения скрипта для архивации данных то **frame7** не пропадает а виснет и ttk.Progressbar не появляется.

```
    def progress_bar(self):
        
        try:
            self.frame7.destroy()
            if self.frame7.winfo_exists() == 0:
                self.progress = ttk.Progressbar(self.frame8, orient=HORIZONTAL,
                    length=300, mode='indeterminate')
                self.progress.grid(columnspan=20, padx=40)
                self.progress.start()
                self.entering_of_changes()
               
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
            
    def entering_of_changes(self):
        
        comment2 = self.comments
        if os.path.exists(self.remarks):
            self.remark = open(homedir+os.sep+remarkfile, 'a')
            x = homedir+os.sep+remarkfile
            self.remark.write(
                time.strftime('%d%m%Y') +
                "-" + time.strftime('%H%M%S') + "-"+comment2+"\n"
                )
            self.source.append(x)
            self.remark.close()
            self.archive()
        else:
            self.remark = open(homedir+os.sep+remarkfile, 'a')
            x = homedir+os.sep+remarkfile
            self.remark.write(
                time.strftime('%d%m%Y') +
                "-" + time.strftime('%H%M%S') + "-" + comment2 + "\n"
                )
            self.source.append(x)
            self.remark.close()
            self.archive()
```

[image: неисчезающий frame]

После того как скрипт выполняется до конца то **self.frame7** исчезает и выводится сообщение об успешном выполнении скрипта.
Я так предполагаю что просто программа при выполнении зависает и из-за этого не пропадает нужный мне виджет.
Подскажите в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Ну видимо у вас где то в функциях вызываемых из entering_of_changes выполняются какие-то длительные операции, блокирующие работу основного потока (подозреваю, что в методе archive). Скорее всего придется вынести их в отдельный поток или процесс.

Comment: По сути наоборот, не программа зависает из-за того что пропадает виджет, а окно зависает из-за того что в основном потоке выполняется какая-то долгая операция, и выполнение долго не возвращается в mainloop.

Comment: спасибо @insolor. Буду пробовать. Да там в функции self.archive() идет процесс архивации на 40 сек продолжительностью.

Comment: @insolor последовал Вашему совету и поместил функцию в отдельный поток и все работает.            x = threading.Thread(target=self.entering_of_changes)